# Is my DIODE in PARALLEL with the Relay (to protect input)

Tags: diodes, relay, parallel

this is my circuit (the path / "read" is from 1 row to N row):

[image: Total]

[image: Detail]

The GREEN wire (from 17 row) is the DATA from a Raspberry (**ANOTHER** GREEN wire enter in 11 row - resistor in serie - and is connected to the base of that transistor) that actions the relay.

RED wire is the POSITIVE and BLACK negative/ground (from the Raspberry).

The circuit performs very well. My doubt is: the DIODE is correctly put in PARALLEL with the relay?

I did read that is better put a diode in parallel and not in series at the POSITIVE, to minimize // eliminate his voltage drop...

Thank you to all!

Comment: I have no idea where a lot of the wires go to just from those pictures. Please post an actual schematic drawing of the circuit you are using and we can tell you if that design is correct or not.

Comment: That is your breadboard and not a circuit (diagram).

Comment: @sineverba, Please draw a circuit diagram with the tool, you can access the tool above the question box (it even has a circuit simulator). EE.SE is different from normal forums, the community expects professionalism (use caps and grammer) and for people to follow the guidelines http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This diode is also known as a "snubber diode" and it is in PARALLEL with the relay coil. If it were not oriented correctly it would be a short circuit in parallel with the relay coil.